# bring button in the centre of the screen

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout

I have designed a Pedigree tree using storyboard on a "iPad Pro Full Screen". When I run it on a iPad Pro Simulator , the root node stays in the middle, which it is suppose to , but other than that when I run it on other simulator the view shift right, example in iPhone 6 screen the root view almost get out of the bounds. Could anybody give me any suggestion how to fix that, I want to show my root node in the middle in all screen ...

[the view start like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj2tH.png)

[I want the view look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEtAM.png)

Comment: Show both code and constraints screenshot about your project.

Comment: uploaded 2 pictures , you will understand easily what I am looking for . n the code is really simple, nothing much to show, all I did designed the buttons and gave them name, and then hide them, after that I made button action, when a button is tapped the button.hidden = false . thats it..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use constraints to do that. Here you have the steps to follow:

1. Go to the Storyboard and select the button you would like to center in the view.
2. Once selected go to the right bottom corner of the storyboard where you will find 4 buttons. Select the second one and check "Horizontally in Container" and "Vertically in Container" like in the picture below and then "Add 2 Constraints".

[image]

3. Unselect the button to center and select it again. Then go to the 4rth button and select "Update Frames".

[image]

You will see that now even rotating the screen it works. Hope that helps!